# ANT Vs MAVEN comparison with respect to Build time

Tags: maven, ant

We are currently using ANT as our build tool and we are proposing our developers to use Maven as their build tool.

Our developers are resisting this change and asking us to give the benefit we will achieve by migrating to Maven. From the blogs what I read Maven can help in reducing build time when compared with ANT.

Can you please give us any reasoning how MAVEN Build script can reduce the build time when compared to ANT? Is this statement true in the first place?

NOTE: Ours is a legacy application that is developed in Core Java.

Are there any other powerful features in Maven which might pique interest of developers that can help us get their confidence in migration to Maven?

Answer (score 1):

Transitive dependency resolution,  standardised builds, lots of plugins, works with Maven repositories which are the de facto standard for storing Java artifacts.

Comment: Automatic support within IDE's. Automatic release procedures, better reuse of artifacts...

Answer (score -1):

- maven **can** be faster than ant, if you know how to

  - structure your code into modules
  - use parallel build of (multiple) modules (a feature ANT really don't has)
  - use semi-incremental build (use newest compiler-plugin) - build only modules, which have changed files or which depend on other changed modules

other benefits are

- maven **can** help you, to describe your build in a more standardised and structured way

  - standard project layout (folder src/main/java src/test/java ...)
  - clear build-process with a strict path of executed steps
- clear definition of used dependencies

  - thirdparty dependencies
  - in-project dependencies
- many helpers for a clear CI/CD setup like

  - plugins supporting gitflow
  - plugins supporting special release processes
  - plugins supporting integration-testing